# Sql query only functions if all records exist

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

```
DELETE FROM Profile, Images, Schedules 
 USING Profile 
INNER JOIN Images USING(profile_id) 
INNER JOIN Schedules USING(profile_id) 
     WHERE Profile.profile_id = 47
```

I have this piece of mysql code that deletes all the records that has profile 47. 
However let's say Schedules doesn't have 47, then the whole query doesnt delete the other records from the other tables.

Basically I want it to delete everything regardless of whether or not schedules has a record.

The other option is query the database to check the Schedules table before doing the delete query?

Comment: then why are you doing the INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an OUTER join to access the tables that might not have supporting records:

```
DELETE FROM p, i, s
      USING PROFILE p 
  LEFT JOIN IMAGES i ON i.profile_id = p.profile_id
  LEFT JOIN SCHEDULES s ON s.profile_id = p.profile_id
      WHERE p.profile_id = 47
```

Here's a [good primer on JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it simpler to do:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM Schedules WHERE Profile_ID = 47;
DELETE FROM Images    WHERE Profile_ID = 47;
DELETE FROM Profile   WHERE Profile_ID = 47;
COMMIT;
```

And wrap that into a stored procedure if appropriate.

Comment: interesting. I've never seen this method before... Does it act as one query?

Comment: In theory yes, it's the A from ACID ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID ) In practise it depends on the dbms and the engine that you use.

Comment: Why do in three/etc queries what you can do in one?  @Adam: SQL Server and MySQL are the only DBs I know of that support JOINs in DELETE statements -- this is your only option on Oracle, last I checked.

Comment: if this method is the A from ACID, then it will not do any DELETE's if one of them is not fulfilled?

Comment: @Adam: as written, it depends on the error processing that the system does. Assuming the BEGIN succeeds (and starts a transaction), then you only want the commit if all three operations succeed, where deleting 0 rows from a table *must* count as success if there are zero rows in it to delete. How to achieve that is DBMS-specific.  It is one reason for thinking a stored procedure migh be a good idea; it can bury the gruesome details in code written once and invoked when needed. Starting a new transaction might not be good either; you might want to set a savepoint and rollback to it on error.

Answer (score 0):

You could just switch to LEFT JOINs.  this removes `Profile where id=47` + any related records found in Images and Schedules.

```
DELETE FROM Profile, Images, Schedules 
 USING Profile 
LEFT JOIN Images USING(profile_id) 
LEFT JOIN Schedules USING(profile_id) 
     WHERE Profile.profile_id = 47
```